# I'm trying to convert normal php code to codeigniter format with ajax functions calling other views

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to be able to pass this code to php codeigniter but i can't find out how to load another view within a view.

what I have tried in a jquery function call is this

```
   function fetch_data(){
       $.ajax({
           /*normal call with php*/  
           /*url:"select.php",*/
           /*tried this with php codeigniter*/
           /*url: "<?=base_url('view/select')?>",*/
           /*and tried this with php codeigniter*/
           /*url: "<?= $select;?>",*/
           /*this last one comes from the controller shown bellow*/
           method:"POST",
           success:function(data){
               $('#live_data').html(data);
           }
       });
    }
```

controller code to display data into view:

```
<?php
//code...
//I was thinking of sending the view through the data array and call it when 
//I needed it but it doesn't work or I don't know if I'm doing something wrong
$data['select'] = $this->load->view('select', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view ('main_view', $data);
?>
```

both views files are inside my views folder

```
main_view.php
select.php
```

this is the code that I have so far:

```
<html>
      <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
           <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="table-responsive">
                     <div id="live_data"></div>            
                </div>
           </div>
      </body>
 </html>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function fetch_data(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"select.php",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                $('#live_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function formatDecimal(val, n) {
        n = n || 2;
        var str = "" + Math.round ( parseFloat(val) * Math.pow(10, n) );
        while (str.length <= n) {
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        var pt = str.length - n;
        return str.slice(0,pt) + "." + str.slice(pt);
    }

    fetch_data();
    function edit_data(id, text, column_name){
        $.ajax({
            url:"edit.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:id,
                text:text,
                column_name:column_name
            },
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                /*alert(data);*/
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
        /* this function would also add the prices to the table*/ 
        var price = $('#price').text();
        var final_price = $('#final_price').text();
        if(price == ''){
            alert("Enter Price");
            return false;
        }
        if(final_price == ''){
            alert("Enter Final Price");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{price:price, final_price:final_price},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                fetch_data();
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id1");
        var price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, price, "price");
        /*I'm trying so that I can add the new input price with the old total to give the exact value*/
        $total = parseFloat( price ) + parseFloat( $('#price_total').value );
        $('#price_total').value = formatDecimal(total);
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.final_price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id2");
        var final_price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, final_price, "final_price");
    });


});
```

select.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
$output = '';  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th width="10%">Id</th>
    <th width="40%">Price</th>
    <th width="40%">Final Price</th>
    <th width="10%">Delete</th>
    </tr>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $final_price_total = 0;
    $price_total = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td class="price" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["price"].'</td>
            <td class="final_price" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["final_price"].'</td>
            <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
            $final_price_total += $row["final_price"];
            $price_total += $row["price"];
        }
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="price_total" id="price_total" name="price_total" value="'.$price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$price_total.'</td>
            <td class="final_price_total" id="final_price_total" name="final_price_total" value="'.$final_price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$final_price_total.'</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            ';
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="price" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="final_price" contenteditable></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
}
else{
    $output .= '<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>
</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Wat ur trying to do ?

Comment: @Raja I'm trying to load the view that's in ajax when its function is called. I should have the whole view of main_view.php and main_view calles select when there is a change but main_view is always open and select is a view within main_view

Comment: First of all ur following a bad pattern in `select.php` you should follow MVC way.

Comment: Anyway, you can't call `.php` files in Ajax url. It either should be declared in routes or can call as `url:controller_name/function_name`

Comment: @Raja I can't call the view direclty like this url: `"<?=base_url('view/select')?>"`

Comment: Yes @learningbyexample. we are unable to call view file directly in codeIgniter. follow the MVC format